# Keep first value, remove repetitions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in the form:

```
ID  ProcessName User    Comment
1   Process1    User1   done
2   Process2    User2   done
3   Process3    User3   done
4   Process4    USer4   proceed
5   Process5    User5   done
6   Process5    User5   redone
7   Process6    User6   
8   Process6    User6   done
9   Process6    User6
```

I would like to write a query that maintains the first instance of Process6 and ignores the other Process6-related rows. I would like to preserve the Process5 repetition, so unfortunately a distinct will not work for me. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is a conditional `WITH TIES`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By case when ProcessName='Process6'
               then row_number() over (partition by ProcessName order by ID)
               else 1 
          end
```

**Results**

```
ID  ProcessName User    Comment
1   Process1    User1   done
2   Process2    User2   done
3   Process3    User3   done
4   Process4    USer4   proceed
5   Process5    User5   done
6   Process5    User5   redone
7   Process6    User6            -- << Note only 1 Process 6
```

**EDIT - A Slightly More Performant Approach**

```
Select ID
      ,ProcessName
      ,User
      ,Comment
 From  (
        Select * 
              ,RN = case when ProcessName='Process6'
                         then row_number() over (partition by ProcessName order by ID)
                         else 1 
                     end
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Where RN=1
```

Comment: Upvote for finally recognizing that `where rn=1` is more performant, I know you've pushed `top 1 with ties` a lot in the past

Comment: @Charlieface I've said it before, WITH TIES is just another tool in the belt.  Not every table is millions of rows and as you progress in your career, you will realize performance is not the only metric.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.processName <> 'Process6' or
      t.id = (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.processName = t.processName
             );
```

With an index on `(processName, id)`, I wouldn't be surprised if this outperformed other methods.

Or if you want to obfuscate the code a bit:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.processName = t.processName and
                        t2.processName = 'Process6' and
                        t2.id < t.id
                 );
```